# IOS Scrollview Marquee style

Tags: iphone

I have a set of 4 images that i want to show in a `UIScrollView`. This scroll view contains ad banners. So they have to keep scrolling vertically down automatically similar to marquee effect - user does not need to touch the screen to scroll.This process should keep repeating.

If the user touches the screen, the scrolling should stop & when user re-touches the screen the scrolling should restart from where it had left.

Comment: anything you have tried?please give snippet of your code that you have tried?

Comment: you need to mix paging with time https://code.google.com/p/iphone-infinite-horizontal-scroller/     use timer with it to make scrolling automatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have done it finally :-) .
Call the below method from viewDidLoad

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(scrollTheScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Now implement the method

```
-(void)scrollTheScrollView{

static int i=0;

i++;

if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.y == 700.0)//This 700.0 will be different for you
    i=0;

NSLog(@"Content offset in scrolling method is %@",self.scrollView);

[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, i*5)];}
```

Comment: Putting last line: `setContentOffset` under `UIView` animation will also help smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

There is as simpler way, I guess. [**UIImageView**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can help you. **Follow these Steps :**

**1) Add 4 `UIImageView`s Vertically Down.**

**2) Create 4 Different Arrays for these ImageViews.**

```
NSArray *frames1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageWithName:@"a.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"b.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"c.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"d.png"],nil];
NSArray *frames2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageWithName:@"b.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"c.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"d.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"a.png"],nil];
NSArray *frames3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageWithName:@"c.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"d.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"a.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"b.png"],nil];
NSArray *frames4 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageWithName:@"d.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"a.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"b.png"],[UIImage imageWithName:@"c.png"],nil];
```

**3) Provide these Arrays to all these different ImageViews.**

```
yourImageView1.animationImages = frames1;
yourImageView2.animationImages = frames2;
yourImageView3.animationImages = frames3;
yourImageView4.animationImages = frames4;
```

**4) You can add some Effects also...**

```
// all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
yourImageView.animationDuration = 1.75;
// repeat the annimation forever
yourImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
```

**5) Simply `startAnimating` the ImageViews.**

```
[yourImageView1 startAnimating]; 
[yourImageView2 startAnimating]; 
[yourImageView3 startAnimating]; 
[yourImageView4 startAnimating];
```

**6) You can always use `-touchesEnded` method to start and stop Animation.**

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([[touches anyObject] view] == yourImageView1) {
        //Here you can write the code to stop and start Animation of UIImageView
    }
}
```

I think this will give you the effect what you want.

GoodLuck !!!

Comment: Nice.. great logic.! +1 for it. But I doubt if it would give the same marquee effect?! May be it will but...... Hv u tried the code

Comment: Thanks Vin.The code is good. I tried it but it does not give the marquee effect .

Comment: @Priyanshu : I didn't try it. But I am quite sure, some customization can provide that effect (If you really understand the logic behind it).

Answer (score 0):

I made an API for this, if you're interested.

https://github.com/dokun1/DOMarqueeLabel